# Select an element by ID that contains number between square brackets

Tags: jquery, regex, input

I need to set values for all inputs with ids like re_widget[num][widget_id] . Now I have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
var result = /^\d{1,2}$/;
$('input[id="re_widget[+result+][widget_id]"]').val("my_value");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Name: <input id="re_widget[1][widget_id]" type="text" name="user1"></p>
<p>Name: <input id="re_widget[2][widget_id]" type="text" name="user2"></p>
<p>Name: <input id="re_widget[3][widget_id]" type="text" name="user3"></p>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this : $('input[id="re_widget[' +result+ '][widget_id]"]').val("my_value");

Comment: That regex isn't being used on any value. How is button supposed to relate to input? There is no current relationship shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Special Character

`[` is a special character in jquery, to use it as part of the query, you need to put a `\` before

The following code will change the input element's values:

```
function setValue(id, value) {
  $('#re_widget\\[' + id + '\\]\\[widget_id\\]').val(value);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    setValue(1, 'hello');
    setValue(2, 'world');
    setValue(3, 'leon');
  });
});
```

#### [Online Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9IfNXXNFlKC8Ch3ILzZq?p=preview)